Как повесить аспект на метод, помеченный @PostConstruct?
Как повесить аспект на метод, помеченный @PostConstruct?. На другие методы данного класса аспекты срабатывают
package ru.test

@Component
public TestClass(){
   public void test() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void testPostСonstruct(){
}
}
}

@Component
@Aspect
public class TestAspect() {

@After("execution(* ru.test.TestClass.test())")
    public void testEvent(JoinPoint joinPoint){
 // Этот аспект срабатывает
}

@After("execution(* ru.test.TestClass.testPostСonstruct())")
    public void testPostСonstruct(JoinPoint joinPoint){
 // Этот аспект НЕ срабатывает
}

}

Если я не ошибаюсь, AOP работает только для тех методов, которые вы самостоятельно вызываете в каком-либо месте вашего кода. А метод, помеченный этой аннотацией, вызывается автоматически Spring-ом после создания бина, который он также создаёт сам.

печально, если так
